# Changing the Java version from 1.8 to 13 cause problems

Tags: java, eclipse

I working in Eclipse on Windows.
I tried to change the version of java from 1.8 to 13 but I,m getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at java.base/java.io.Reader.(Reader.java:167)
>
> at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.(InputStreamReader.java:72)

The problem is in a function where I load data. What should I do to avoid this problem?

code:

```java
    private static int loadShader(String file, int type){
        StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();
        try{
            InputStream in = Class.class.getResourceAsStream(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                shaderSource.append(line).append("//\n");
            }
            reader.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        int shaderID = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
        GL20.glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);
        GL20.glCompileShader(shaderID);
        if(GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS )== GL11.GL_FALSE){
            System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, 500));
            System.err.println("Could not compile shader!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return shaderID;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using - you *will* get this if you pass `null` into the `InputStreamReader` constructor, but we've no idea what stream you're passing in. If you can show a [mcve] it's much, much more likely that we'll be able to help.

Comment: Poor title. Revise to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 2):

## Java modularization

The line

```
InputStream in = Class.class.getResourceAsStream(file);
```

is suspicious.

Java 9 introduced the [Java Platform Module System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System). That means `Class.getResourceAsStream()` can only find resources that are in the same module as the class. I doubt that your shader resource is in the [`java.base`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.base-summary.html) module.

Replace `Class` with the name of the class where your `loadShader()` method is declared:

```
InputStream in = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(file);
```

(Assuming that `loadShader()` is declared in the class `MyClass`)

Comment: I really thank you and sorry that my question is poor. I will do it better in future.